# Manipulate files on Android phone with Java on Windows 10

Tags: java, android, windows

I recently got an Android phone (a ZTE Majesty Pro LTE), and because I manage my (sizable) music library with iTunes I wrote a small Java program to sync the checked songs in my iTunes database with a user-specified directory (the idea being that I can sync with the music folder on my phone). However, I've hit a brick wall in that I am unable to figure out the path of my phone when it is connected to my Windows 10 computer.  Every single place that lists the path of the phone itself or files on the phone shows it is being "This PC\Z798BL\...".  However, the Java file reading functions don't recognize this is a valid path.  I've searched and searched, but nothing I've found has helped me.  I can copy to and otherwise manipulate the files on my phone in File Explorer, so surely there's some way to do the same thing programmatically?

Things I've tried:
-Enabling debug mode.  Not sure why this would help but I saw it suggested on sort-of-similar questions.  Note that ADB works perfectly with my phone.
-Downloading the ZTE drivers from Google's OEM USB Driver page.  The installation does not seem to have done anything as Device Manager still lists the phone as using some Microsoft driver from 2006.  I tried manually installing the driver but Device Manager tells me it doesn't find any drivers that work with my device.

Comment: The phone probably uses the MTP-protocol, so for details read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16303072/987358

Comment: Yup, you're right.  I managed to get it to work by installing Linux 
Mint and using go-mtpfs to mount my phone and access it via the file system.  I really wish there was an option to use Android phones as mass storage devices instead of using MTP